# Does Shrinking A Log (.ldf) Database File Delete Temp Tables

Tags: sql-server

I was just shrinking some .ldf log files to reduce some space on my server and I was wondering if when I do so if I am deleting any temp tables that are currently on that server?  I wouldn't think so because I would think that those would be stored in the .mdf Data files, but just figured that I would ask!

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the sql tag, and instead add a tag for the dbms product used.

Comment: if you are shrinking LDF then it will delete log data files and free up space but no connection with temp tables and more over they relate to TEMPDB database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Temp tables are created in the tempdb database only. Shrinking files on user databases will not impact tempdb.
2. Temp tables are objects, and are stored in the data file. Log files contain the transaction history of the database.  Maintenance operations on a log file could remove the history in the file, but will not remove objects.
3. Shrinking a database file simply removes unused pages to free up space in a file. If a page is being used, it will not be touched by the shrink operation.

So the answer to you question is no, shrinking log files will not delete temp tables.